# Build a Qt project and publish it on GitHub

Tags: c++, linux, qt, github, deployment

I'm new to QT and I made an app with it and now I want to publish it on GitHub.
So I tried to commit the code to GitHub and so that the user wouldn't need to have Qt installed I added an executable that I got by building the project in Qt Creator.

As I tried to get it to run in a virtual machine (Debian) by using

```
sudo chmod +x myapp
```

it gave the following error :

```
./myapp: error while loading shared libraries: libQtPrintSupport.so.6: not open shared object file: no such file or dictionary
```

how can i fix that error or is there a better way to do it? Would it be an option to add a .zip file?

Comment: My advice is to publish the source code including your .pro files or CMakeList.txt if you use CMake and don't publish any compiled binary files at all. Let the user install for whatever OS they are using giving them instructions how to build like most other opensource projects.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deploy Qt applications for Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41674425/how-to-deploy-qt-applications-for-linux)